# How to do multiple simultaneous overlays from a single artboard in adobe XD?

Tags: adobe, overlay

I am making a mobile dropdown menu in AdobeXD.

Besides my home page I have two other artboards; the menu itself and a button.

All I want to do is trigger the menu to slide down as well as overlay the exit button on top of the button that triggers the effect in the first place.

It will overlay the exit button but the menu is nowhere to be seen when I preview it. At best I can get one or the other to happen but not both. WTF.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I can tell there is currently no way to do multiple overlays.

The best solution is to put everything into one overlay.

If you need to trigger a second overlay from the first overlay, include all of the previous items from the initial overlay and put them into the second one as well.

It is not ideal but it is the only solution I have currently found.